# Spark job just hangs with large data

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr, amazon-emr

I am trying to query from s3 (15 days of data). I tried querying them separately (each day) it works fine. It works fine for 14 days as well. But when I query 15 days the job keeps running forever (hangs) and the task # is not updating.

My settings :

I am using 51 node cluster r3.4x large with dynamic allocation and maximum resource turned on.

All I am doing is =

```
val startTime="2017-11-21T08:00:00Z"
val endTime="2017-12-05T08:00:00Z"

val start = DateUtils.getLocalTimeStamp( startTime )
val end = DateUtils.getLocalTimeStamp( endTime )

val days: Int = Days.daysBetween( start, end ).getDays

val files: Seq[String] = (0 to days)
      .map( start.plusDays )
      .map( d => s"$input_path${DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy/MM/dd" ).print( d )}/*/*" )

sqlSession.sparkContext.textFile( files.mkString( "," ) ).count
```

When I run the same with 14 days, I got 197337380 (count) and I ran the 15th day separately and got 27676788. But when I query 15 days total the job hangs

Update :

The job works fine with :

```
  var df = sqlSession.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema)

    for(n <- files ){
      val tempDF = sqlSession.read.schema( schema ).json(n)
      df = df(tempDF)
    }

df.count
```

But can some one explain why it works now but not before ?

UPDATE : After setting mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize to 256 GB it works fine now.

Comment: I initially had 32MB but still same issue so tried changing that but still job hangs

Comment: yeah. It is s3 but what I don't understand is it works for 14 days but not 15 days. And it works for different 15 days though. If it is data issue then I should have error for that 15th day when I ran that day alone separately

Comment: Your spark driver definitely does not need so much memory and not clear where you got 149 for the number of executors

Comment: how many cores per executors are you using?

Comment: can you please post the yarn resource manager screen shot to understand more?

Answer (score 11):

Dynamic allocation and maximize resource allocation are both different settings, one would be disabled when other is active. With Maximize resource allocation in EMR, 1 executor per node is launched, and it allocates all the cores and memory to that executor.

I would recommend taking a different route. You seem to have a pretty big cluster with 51 nodes, not sure if it is even required. However, follow this rule of thumb to begin with, and you will get a hang of how to tune these configurations.

- Cluster memory - minimum of 2X the data you are dealing with.

Now assuming 51 nodes is what you require, try below:

- r3.4x has 16 CPUs - so you can put all of them to use by leaving one for the OS and other processes.
- Set your number of executors to 150 - this will allocate 3 executors per node.
- Set number of cores per executor to 5 (3 executors per node)
- Set your executor memory to roughly total host memory/3 = 35G
- You got to control the parallelism (default partitions), set this to number of total cores you have ~ 800
- Adjust shuffle partitions - make this twice of number of cores - 1600

Above configurations have been working like a charm for me. You can monitor the resource utilization on Spark UI.

Also, in your yarn config `/etc/hadoop/conf/capacity-scheduler.xml` file, set `yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator` to `org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator` - which will allow Spark to really go full throttle with those CPUs. Restart yarn service after change.

Answer (score 0):

You should be increasing the executor memory and # executors, If the data is huge try increasing the Driver memory.

My suggestion is to not use the dynamic resource allocation and let it run and see if it still hangs or not (Please note that spark job can consume entire cluster resources and make other applications starve for resources try this approach when no jobs are running). if it doesn't hang that means you should play with the resource allocation, then start hardcoding the resources and keep increasing resources so that you can find the best resource allocation you can possibly use.

Below links can help you understand the resource allocation and optimization of resources.

http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/understanding-resource-allocation-configurations-spark-application/

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42803/spark-on-yarn-executor-resource-allocation-optimiz.html

Comment: Tried updating the driver memory, still same issue